# What is the difference depending on where the global validation pipe is set in Nest.js?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

There are two different ways to apply validation pipe globally. I can't figure out the difference between those.

#### method 1

```
// app.module.ts

import { APP_PIPE } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [    
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE, // <-- here
      useValue: new ValidationPipe({}),
    },
  ]
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  // ...
}
```

#### method 2

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#auto-validation

```
// main.ts

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule); 
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({})); // <-- here
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

When we are applying a global validation pipe in `main.ts` we bind the validation pipe throughout the application. But it does miss out on the modules registered from outside the context of the application. On the other hand, when we apply a validation pipe in the module scope the pipe binds on only the routes for that module. This becomes pretty useful when you want to bind specific pipes to a module.